# Дан массив из 8 байт. Рассматривая его, как массив из 64 бит, посчитать количество единиц

Tags: ассемблер

Дан массив из 8 байт. Рассматривая его, как массив из 64 бит, посчитать количество единиц.

Вот что у меня получилось. Не правильно.

```
START:
      LEA   SI, dbArr ; загрузка адреса
      XOR   DL, DL      ; Счётчик
      MOV   CX, 8       ; номер бита
BYTE_LOOP:
      PUSH  CX.         ; Засылка операнда в стек
      MOV   CX, 8       ; битов в байте
      LODSB.            ; загрузка символов из строки
BIT_LOOP:
      ADC   DL, 1 ; сложение с переносом
      ROR   AL, 0 ; циклический сдвиг в право
      LOOP  BIT_LOOP ; цикл со счётчиком CX
      POP   CX  ; извлечение слова из стека
      LOOP  BYTE_LOOP ; управление циклом

      MOV   AL, DL
      AAM.            ; Коррекция ASCII
      MOV   CX, AX
      TEST  CH, CH
      JNZ    LOW_DIGIT. ; Переход если результат «1»
      MOV   DL, CH
LOW_DIGIT:
      MOV   DL, CL
```

Comment: Для подсчёта единичных битов следует использовать сдвиг/вращение через флаг переноса (`RCL`, скажем, или там `SHL`) и `ADC counter, 0`. Кстати, стек тут не нужен. А вот направление для `LODSB` надо обязательно задавать явно. И читать/считать можно сразу словами - не влияет, а накладных расходов меньше.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/popcnt16-popcnt-popcnt64?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 1):

```
BIT_LOOP:
    ROR AL, 1
    ADC DL, 0 
    LOOP BIT_LOOP
```

и перед первым циклом добавить:

```
    CLD
```